# Power BI Report Builder - KeepTogether/KeepWithGroup not working

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, reportbuilder

I have a .rdl file with the following repeatable tablix:

[Tablix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg8tg.png)

I'm trying to make it so that each instance of the row group is kept together on a page and not split across multiple pages, however it doesn't seem to be working. I have set the KeepTogether and KeepWithGroup values for the group and static rows equal to True & After, however the row groups are still split across pages instead of being pulled into the next page.

[Row Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osHVL.png)
[Row Group Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Cmm.png)

Am I missing something or is it not working as its supposed to? I tried looking at solutions to similar problems however didn't get any of them to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. In this post the person asked this exact problem and the solution is clear, however, the solution does not seem to work: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/Page-Break-within-a-group/m-p/3358711

Answer (score 0):

The solution indicated here partially works: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Report-Server/Page-Break-within-a-group/m-p/3358711

The way I got it to work is to turn entire row group into the sub report and then in the sub report have a table with all the data needed for display.

Keep together seems to only work for 1 row.